# numpy seems to produce strange eignvectors

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I am doing linear algebra (calculating eignvestors) in python using one of Gilbert Strang's books. In his books the matrix A is given as shown below.

[image]

The eignvectors of this matrix are the ones shown in matrix V below

[image]

I am trying to confirm the results using numpy as follows

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg as la

A = np.array([[0,0],
              [0,16]])
eignval, eignvector = la.eig(A)

print (eignvector)
array([[1., 0.],
       [0., 1.]]))
```

We see that the eignvectors derived from numpy are different. It looks like if we exchange the row one with row two we get the correct results. Can someone explain why this happens

Comment: The eigenvectors, in no particular order, are (1,0) and (0,1). Both the textbook's V, and numpy's result, contain those two eigenvectors as their two columns. They just use a different order: V has (0,1) as its first column whereas numpy chooses (1,0) as the first column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html#numpy-linalg-eig), eigenvalues are not necessarily ordered and `eignvector[:, i]` corresponds to the `eignval[i]`.

```
for i in range(2):
    print(f"eigen vector for eigen value {eignval[i]} is {eignvector[:, i]}")
# eigen vector for eigen value 0.0 is [1. 0.]
# eigen vector for eigen value 16.0 is [0. 1.]
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. What if I had a large matrix (e.g 100x100) and I wanted to order the eignvectors in descending order. Which means, in the 1st row we should have the eignvector that corresponds to the highest eignvalue, in the 2nd row the eignvector that corresponds to the 2nd highest eignvalue e.t.c

Comment: @Johny, try something like `eignvector[np.flip(np.argsort(eignval)), :]`